# 7011 - radio ON

Tags: wireless-networking, radio

We have Dell Latitude 7420 laptop, and every day it loses ethernet connection for two seconds.

Every time there is log in EventViewer: Source - Netwtw10, 7011 - radio ON and after that 7012 - radio OFF.

The WiFi is turned Off in internet access, however logs are saying that it is On for 2 seconds.
How to prevent this error when WiFi is not turned ON?

[image: Radio ON]

Comment: Reinstall both wired and wireless network cards and then make sure the wired network Metric is different and higher than (lower number) the wireless Metric. Metric is in Advanced Adapter Properties.